# Substitute a string with a for loop variable in makefile script

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have this makefile recipe :

```bash
.PHONY: test-api4
test-api4: $(HOME)/.halctl
    for version_i in $(candidate_versions); do \
        echo "version_i : $$version_i"; \
        $(eval version3=$(shell sh -c "./a.sh $$version_i" )) \
        echo $(version3); \
    done; \
```

Here I want the shell command to be dynamically picking up values from the candidate_versions list and executing them.

But this doesn't work, this substitution doesn't happen.
Is there a way to do that?

Because the line `echo "version_i : $$version_i"; \` worked, I expected something like `$(eval version3=$(shell sh -c "./a.sh $$version_i" )) \` should also work. But it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that make does not have a shell interpreter built into it.  Make *invokes* a shell, as a separate process, to run the recipe.  So it's simply not possible to replace every aspect of a recipe with an "equivalent" make function, because they are actually very very different.

When make decides a target is out of date, it will **first** *expand* the entire recipe, which expands every make macro, function, etc.  Only then once everything is expanded, will the results of the expansion be passed to the shell as a script to be invoked.  Then the shell runs while make waits for it.  Then the shell exits, and make examines its exit code to see whether it succeeded or not.

So it's simply not possible to put a make function *inside* a loop in the shell and have the shell loop control variable (like `version_i` above) visible to make: that variable doesn't exist until the shell is invoked and it only exists in the shell.

In general, it's almost always wrong to use either `eval` or `shell` make functions, inside a recipe.  There are very rare, very unusual situations where it makes sense but mostly, you shouldn't ever do it.

So to write your recipe you *must* use the shell, like:

```
.PHONY: test-api4
test-api4: $(HOME)/.halctl
        for version_i in $(candidate_versions); do \
            echo "version_i : $$version_i"; \
            version3=$$(./a.sh $$version_i); \
            echo $$version3; \
        done
```

Comment: Hey, this worked like charm, thanks ! Where can I read more into this stuff ? Can you suggest some resources ?

Specifically how does make know what to execute in a shell, how does the string formatting and execution work?

Comment: You can read the GNU Make manual.  For example this section: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html and this section: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipes.html or really, all of it.  I think you're thinking things are a lot more complicated than they really are.  Make takes the recipe in as a string, then it walks through looking for make macros and functions (introduced by an un-escaped `$`) and expands them, then it invokes `/bin/sh -c '<thestring>'` and that's it (of course you can change these behaviors in various ways).